# Format one nested list style to match another list

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib, nested-lists

I have xy coordinates that I'm trying to get to match in length in matplotlib. I need x value list to match the y value nested list pattern so the graph will not draw a line between the lists but rather start and stop with each nested list.

x(time):

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, ...]
```

y(phase)

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, ...]]
```

The list length will vary and so will the length of each nested list.

Comment: Will the lengths of all nested lists be equal per list?

Comment: What have you tried?  If you need to nest the `x` list, then iterate through the `y` lengths, and create your sub-lists in `x`.  If you need `y` to be one-dimensional, then simply flatten it ("flatten" is your search term).

Comment: @chrisz: that's why I didn't go immediately to `np.reshape`, as you did: OP shows 6 in y[0], but 7+ in y[1].

Comment: Yes the lists will always match in length, but once I nested the y list by their unique number, the length of elements changed, causing errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lists are jagged (assuming the total number of elements is equal) you may iterate through `y`, creating chunks from `x` as you iterate.

```
x = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
y = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

curi = 0
fin = []
for i in y:
  fin.append(x[curi:curi+len(i)])
  curi += len(i)

print(fin)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

If you lists are *not* jagged:

```
x.reshape(y.shape)
```

Comment: could you explain what you mean by jagged?

Comment: `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]` == not jagged, `[[1], [1,2,3]]` == jagged.  Basically if any sublists have different lengths

Comment: Thank you! Your solution fixed my lists formatting. Now I just need to get matplotlib to read  the lists properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.split`, which breaks up an array or list at the indices provided as the second parameter:

```
# create random example
>>> y = [list(np.random.randint(0, 10, (np.random.randint(3, 10),))) for j in range(10)]
>>> x = list(np.random.randint(0, 10, (sum(map(len, y)),)))
>>> y
[[6, 8, 4, 5], [1, 3, 6, 3, 7, 8], [1, 5, 9, 6, 4], [2, 7, 3], [8, 3, 6, 8], [0, 6, 4, 4, 6, 9], [5, 4, 8, 3, 8, 1], [6, 4, 7, 2], [2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 5, 7]]
>>> x
[6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 8, 2, 7, 0, 9, 8, 7, 9, 9, 6, 0, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 0, 4, 7, 0, 4, 3, 3, 7, 7, 5, 3]

# split
>>> xs = np.split(x, np.cumsum(np.fromiter(map(len, y), int, count=len(y)-1)))
>>> xs
[array([6, 7, 3, 4]), array([1, 4, 4, 8, 2, 7]), array([0, 9, 8, 7, 9]), array([9, 6, 0]), array([5, 5, 2, 2]), array([5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4]), array([2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5]), array([0, 4, 7, 0]), array([4, 3, 3]), array([7, 7, 5, 3])]
```